# ExtJS Grid Sorting Mayus / Minus

Tags: javascript, extjs

I need to sort a column that contains mayus / minus characters:

[image: Before Sort]

When I click the column Placa for sort, the row **mhu030** goes to the end.

[image: After Sort]

How do I order disregarding case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model's field configuration, specify the field's [type](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-type) to be `string` and the field should be sorted correctly, since ExtJS will then apply the built-in [sort type](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Field-cfg-sortType) [`asUCString`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.SortTypes-method-asUCString) automatically.